# How to optimize this exercise from HackerEarth?

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap

This is my first question here. So I came across [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/pair-sums/description/) problem from HackerEarth and I solved it using a HashMap.
 I think my solution is correct because from all 5 inputs, 3 are correct but the remaining two exceed the time limit. How could I improve my solution?
My solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();

        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            Integer value = map.get(x);
            if(value == null) {
                map.put(x, 1);
            }
            else if(value<=1) map.put(x,2);
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            if(map.containsKey(k-key)) {
                //check if same key
                if(k - key == key){
                    if(map.get(key)>1) {
                        System.out.println("YES");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NO");

    }
}
```

I cannot post input samples here, because they are larger than the body limit of the message....

Comment: I didn't thoroughly read your code but if I understand the task correctly you get the value of `K` as well as an array. Thus why are you using a map? I'd start with iterating over the array and check vs. all following elements. One optimization then could be first sorting the array and using a binary search approach to look for those tuples.

Comment: nope, sorry, I tried solving it with sorting the elements and it is too expensive computationally..

Comment: How did you try to sort?

Comment: well, basically sorting the array is `O(n*lgn)` but his approach is  `O(n)` (well, close to `O(n)` if we do not take into account the coefficients when working with `HashMaps` - but they do exist in reality)

Comment: @Thomas I think it does not matter( even with the best sorting method it will exceed the time limit) - but to answer your question, I used quicksort

Comment: "even with the best sorting method it will exceed the time limit" - that's not true, I just submitted by own solution using `Arrays.sort()` (without skipping elements) and all tests succeeded in 1.2s at max. That's not the most efficient solution but it shows that sorting can help or at least is not too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the first `for` loop, to not include all numbers, just numbers that are are less than `k` (why? because all your numbers are positive and you can't get `k` as a result of an addition where one of the numbers is greater than or equal to `k`)
old code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            Integer value = map.get(x);
            if(value == null) {
                map.put(x, 1);
            }
            else if(value<=1) map.put(x,2);
        }
```

Modified version:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            Integer value = map.get(x);
            if(x < k){
                if(value == null) {
                    map.put(x, 1);
                }
                else if(value<=1) map.put(x,2);
            }
        }
```

Full solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();

        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            Integer value = map.get(x);
            if(x < k){
                if(value == null) {
                    map.put(x, 1);
                }
                else if(value<=1) map.put(x,2);
            }
        }
        ;
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            if(k>=key && map.containsKey(k-key)) {
                //check if same key
                if(k - key == key){
                    if(map.get(key)>1) {
                        System.out.println("YES");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NO");

    }
}
```

Comment: lol. I cannot believe it. It works now. And it does not exceed the time limit.

Comment: I took a look at the input files and there are a lot of numbers greater than `k` in them, so I added all of them into the `HasHap` and that's why it exceeded the time